# phonegap notification in ios not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, requirejs

Phonegap or Cordova notification not working in Backbone, require and javascript.

So the situation is if the USERNAME or PASSWORD is empty it should notify( using phonegap ) but it wont work. Any ideas?

I have this code

```
define([
'jquery',
'backbone',
'underscore',
'base64',
'mobile',
'cordova',
'const',
'text!template/login/login.tpl.html'
],function($, Backbone, _, base64, Mobile, Cordova, Const, template){

if(!Const.USERNAME || !Const.PASSWORD)
        {
            navigator.notification.alert("Invalid Username/Password!");
            $("input").val("");
        }else{

            var auth = EncodeAuth(Const.USERNAME,Const.PASSWORD);

            var sendAuthorization = function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth)
            };

            this.model.save(this.model, {
                beforeSend : sendAuthorization,
                success: function(model,result){
                    if(result.ErrorMessage === null)
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(result.Message));
                        $("input").val("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(result.ErrorMessage));
                        $("input").val("");
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. I used the wrong version of cordova or phonegap. I'm using the android version since i'm also checking it on windows.